# Why does only one BrowserView work with Electron?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron

I'm trying to have two `BrowserView` in the same window, side by side. This code runs:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');
function createWindow() {
    browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 600 });
    let browserView1 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
    let browserView2 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
    browserWindow.setBrowserView(browserView1);
    browserWindow.setBrowserView(browserView2);
    browserView1.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600 });
    browserView2.setBounds({ x: 600, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600 });
    browserView1.webContents.loadURL('https://www.example.com');
    browserView2.webContents.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
    browserWindow.on('closed', function () { browserWindow = null; });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

but only the second `BrowserView` is displayed.

**How to have both displayed?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `BrowserView` is currently an experimental feature of Electron.  Most of its functionality is still in beta releases of Electron.  Since this is still only in beta releases of Electron it is not safe to use in production releases.

Having said that we can still get this to work.  First, install the Electron beta `npm install --save electron@v5.0.0-beta.5`.

Then change your Electron file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView } = require('electron');
function createWindow() {
    browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 600 });
    let browserView1 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
    let browserView2 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
    browserWindow.addBrowserView(browserView1);
    browserWindow.addBrowserView(browserView2);
    browserView1.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600 });
    browserView2.setBounds({ x: 600, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600 });
    browserView1.webContents.loadURL('https://www.example.com');
    browserView2.webContents.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
    browserWindow.on('closed', function () { browserWindow = null; });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Instead of using `setBrowserView()` use `addBrowserView()`.

[Feature request on git](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16148)

Comment: Thank you @JimmyLeahy, it works indeed with Electron5.0.0-beta.5. Out of curiosity, how do you think that the project [wexond](https://github.com/wexond/wexond) does to display in one single window: a browser page (requiring `BrowserView`) + top UI buttons / tabs (requiring another `BrowserView` to display a local .html file for UI/buttons)?